# regex for age with 2 decimal points

Tags: javascript, regex

What is regex for age with 2 decimal points value with max value 99.11

Valid examples:

```
1
12.01
16.06
20.11
```

Invalid examples:

```
.0
1.12 (decimal value should be <12)
1.13  (decimal value should be <12)
12.111
100.00 (2 digit before decimal point, max 99.11)
```

I have tried `^[0-9]\d{0,1}(\.\d[0-1]\d{0,1})*(,\d+)?$` regex but it is not following all criteria.
can anyone help me?

Comment: What's your language?

Comment: @Tân javascript, see i have updated tag

Comment: This maybe enough `^\d{1,2}(\.(?:0\d|1[01]))?$`

Comment: If you need to check age, why do you curb a human life at `99.11` years?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with this pattern:

```
/^\d{1,2}(\.(0[0-9]|1[01]))?$/
```

```js
var pattern = /^\d{1,2}(\.(0[0-9]|1[01]))?$/;

console.log(pattern.test('1'));
console.log(pattern.test('12.01'));
console.log(pattern.test('16.06'));
console.log(pattern.test('20.11'));

console.log(pattern.test('.0'));
console.log(pattern.test('1.12'));
console.log(pattern.test('1.13'));
console.log(pattern.test('12.111'));
console.log(pattern.test('100.00'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
/^\d\d?(\.(0\d|1[01]))?$/
```

Description:

- `^\d\d?` - from the start of the string, match 1 or 2 numbers
- After that/those numbers, optionally match `.` plus 2 numbers
- The two numbers must be 0 and any number, else 1 and 0 or 1
- Anchor to the end of the string

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the two different patterns of floating part, which must be handled with a `|`.

A character-optimal solution is `^\d{1,2}(\.[0]\d|\.1[01])?$`.